# Connection activation failed (2) Active connection removed before it was initialized

Tags: wireless, network-manager, internet

The ubuntu version is `16.04` My network is working fine until a particular point. After that, it got automatically disconnected. If I tried to connect to the wifi again it shows the following prompt every time.

[image]

I have tried to restart the network manage using
`sudo service network-manager restart` command, but it doesn't work.

The only solution is `reboot` the system every time. Sometime It is `not showing the wifi option` in the top.I am tired of reboot the system every time.

I don't find any solution in askubuntu for this problem. Could someone help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Which version is this?

Comment: ubuntu os version is `16.04`

Comment: I’m having the same issue. Have you solve it yet?

Comment: @MoneyBall no bro..  not solved yet.. waiting for the perfect answer..

Comment: Hi did you find the answer? I have same problem

Answer (score 3):

Go to Preferences->Network Connections. Remember all the proper settings of current connection - you will need to rewrite it. Then delete connection and add it again. It worked for me on VirtualBox Lubuntu machine.

Answer (score 1):

My words might not have the cure to your issue, but, from the error message, it seems that something is eating your internet link.

This usually happens with either a malfunctioning network card, or a really bad network card driver!

Otherwise, something on your system is interfering with your NIC software and/or Network Manager? A firewall/antivirus, perhaps?